# PHP: What is the difference between an exception and a catchable fatal error?

Tags: php, exception, try-catch, fatal-error

I am a bit confused about those terms and their exact meaning / handling in PHP:

***Exception*** could be defined like this:

> When an error occurs within a method, the method creates an object and
>   hands it off to the runtime system. The object, called an exception
>   object, contains information about the error, including its type and
>   the state of the program when the error occurred. Creating an
>   exception object and handing it to the runtime system is called
>   throwing an exception.

Exceptions can be caught and handled.

***Fatal Error*** could be defined like this:

> Fatal errors are critical errors - for example, instantiating an
>   object of a non-existent class, or calling a non-existent function.
>   These errors cause the immediate termination of the script, and PHP's
>   default behavior is to display them to the user when they take place.

Fatal errors can not necessarily be caught (they do not throw usual exceptions), otherwise there would be no more specific ***Catchable Fatal Error***.

However how is a ***Catchable Fatal Error*** different from a normal ***Exception***? And is it handled the same? Is a catchable fatal error a specific type of exception or not?

Comment: Its handled with `set_error_handler`. But know some catchable fatal errors are now normal exceptions in php7 which you can use `try catch` on. http://docs.php.net/errorfunc.constants E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Fatal errors can not necessarily be caught (they do not throw usual
>   exceptions)

Prior to version 7, this was the case. Fatal errors used to stop the script dead in its tracks. However, as of version 7, they're now presented as catchable exceptions. This allows you to gracefully recover from pretty significant issues.

> However how is a Catchable Fatal Error different from a normal
>   Exception?

They both implement Throwable, but with different anchor classes:

```
Throwable
    Error
        ParseError
        ...
    Exception
        RuntimeException
        ...
```

> And is it handled the same?

Yep, you can catch them, just like Exceptions.

> Is a catchable fatal error a
>   specific type of exception or not?

Depends on your semantics. A catchable fatal error is an exception but it's not an `Exception`, if you get my meaning. You can differentiate like this;

```
// "traditional" exceptions
try {
    throw new Foo();
} catch (Exception $e) {
}

// v7 catchable fatal errors
try {
    $not_an_object->not_a_method();
} catch (Error $e) {
}

// both
try { 
} catch (Throwable $e) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks good answer - just one clarification: Are ALL fatal errors in PHP 7 catchable? Such that I can even catch an "Allowed memory size exhausted" error for instance?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that not all are catchable. From the original RFC: "Some errors are easy to change to exceptions, others are more complicated. Some are impossible, like the memory limit or execution time limit errors. The E_CORE_ERROR type can't be converted to use exceptions because it occurs during startup (at least if used correctly). Converting E_COMPILE_ERROR to exceptions would also require some significant changes to the compiler."